# How to form Jacobian Matrix From Differential Equations.

Tags: matrices, ordinary-differential-equations, mathematical-modeling, jacobian

This is my first time using the StackExchange and I was hoping someone could help me find the Jacobian Matrix for the ODEs I am working with. I am working with three populations; Humans, Ticks, and Carriers. The ODEs involving exposed and infected compartments are:

```
    EH/dt = (βHH * IH) + (βCH * IC) + (βTH * IT) - (deltaH + muH)EH
    IH/dt = (deltaH * EH) - (alpha + gamma + muH) * IH)
    ET/dt = (piT * βTTV * IT) + (βCT * IC) + (BTTH * IT) - (deltaT + muT) *  ET
    IT/dt = (deltaT * ET) - (muT * IT)
    EC/dt = (βTC * IT) - (deltaC + muC) * EC
    IC/dt = (deltaC * EC) - (muC * IC)
```

Where alpha represents the human recovery rate, gamma represents the human death rate from the disease, piT represents the tick birth rate, mu represents the natural death rate respectively, and delta represents the incubation period respectively for humans, ticks, and carriers. Please let me know if there is any clarification needed or any further information that would be useful such as my full model or code. Thank you very much.

Comment: Did you mean EH or something else in that first line? That isn't linear if it is EH unless you have an EH derivative as well that is linear

Comment: @cmitch You are correct they are nonlinear differential equations. What does this mean in terms of obtaining the Jacobian matrix?

Comment: @Moo I am not sure how to write it in matrix form. All I have is my model and I am trying to find the basic reproduction number. How would I go about writing this in matrix form to make it more readable?

Comment: You can't find a jacobian then, but only a jacobian approximation around a point, as the jacobian implies there is a matrix such that $\frac{df}{dx} = Ax$, where $x$ is your vector of variables and $f$ is the function mapping $x$ to the differential equations. This implies each differential equation is linear

Comment: Here explains how to approximate the equations with a jacobian. However, if you expected a true jacobian, your equations are probably wrong. https://www.math.uci.edu/~ndonalds/math3d/nonlinear.pdf

Comment: @cmitch I trust that you are correct I just am confused on how any SIR model made of ODEs uses a Jacobian matrix to find R0. I have looked at examples of this I am just confused on how to do it with my own equations.

Comment: @cmitch For example this is an article I have been referring to in which they use the NGM to find R0. https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC6453107/

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by Ro here, and not sure how to easily figure out from the article what you are asking, but what I said above works for finding jacobians. You can use the jacobian at a point to estimate the function ($f(x) \approx \frac{df}{dx}_{x=a} * (x-a) + f(a)$), so maybe something related to that

Comment: @Nicole The references of cmitch seem appropriate. In general when facing  nonlinear systems we solve them iteratively (usually via a numerical algorithm). This implies linearizing the original system of equations about a known point (or state) using an initial guess and "turn the crank" until convergence via an iterative algorithm like Newton-Raphson. The Jacobian is employed to update the solution iteratively.

Comment: MathJax, please...

Comment: @basco Thank you very much for your reply. This is my first time working with this I am a computer science major. Do you have any insight on how I would go about linearizing the equations? This model I have coded my model into R and I am trying to use a next generation matrix to find the basic reproduction number. I know this is a very broad question but with my equations do you know where I should start? I apologize if this question is confusing I am very stuck.

Comment: @K.defaoite What do you mean by this?

Comment: @Nicole Use MathJax, not code blocks. Here is a [guide](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Comment: Nicole, I've just read your comment. For getting the precise help you need it may be necessary to reformulate the question. The computation of a Jacobian for a system of ODEs follows roughly the steps in my answer below. But, that is not what you are looking for and the question does not state it. The model seems to be compartmental, i.e. it is of the form $\dot{\textbf{x}}(\textbf{x})=\textbf{F}(\textbf{x})-\textbf{V}(\textbf{x})$. Include this information in your question (explain what F and V are) and indicate that you want to use the next-generation matrix.

Comment: @Basco I appreciate your comment, after further research and understanding I realize my question was not very well thought out or well worded. Thank you kindly for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the left hand side of your equations "bla/dt" rates and denote them as $\dot{x}_i$ for $i=1,2,...,N$ ($N=5$ in your case). These quantities constitute the components of a vector $\dot{\textbf{x}}$. The right hand side of the equations is another vector $\textbf{X}$ and each component is ${X_i}$. The Jacobian matrix $\textbf{J}$ has components $J_{ij}=\partial X_i/\partial x_j|_{x_c}$, i.e. the jacobian is $N \times N$. Notice that after computing the derivatives, the result is evaluated at $\textbf{x}_c$, which is a "point state" where you know the value of all the variables.

It is possible to think about linear approximations in terms of Taylor expansions. In your system, and for computational purposes $\textbf{X}(\textbf{x}_c+\Delta)=\textbf{X}(\textbf{x}_c)+\text{J} \Delta+hot$, where the higher order terms ($hot$) are ignored and $\Delta$ is what it is used to update the solution in the next iteration.